# can not achieve that useEffect works properly with dependencies

Tags: reactjs

I want to recall initFetch() just if respDC or editDc changes.
I try differents ways, but at the end if i put depencies, i have a inffinite loop.

```
const { user } = useAuth();  
  
  const {
    responsable,
    editor,
    matricula
  } = user; 

const respDc = JSON.parse(responsable); 
  const editDc = JSON.parse(editor);
  
  const initFetch = useCallback (() => {
    for (let dc of respDc){
      dispatch(getTopicsByDcResponsable({dc: dc, token: accessToken}));      
    }
    for (let dc of editDc){
      dispatch(getTopicsbyDcentroEdit({dc: dc, token: accessToken}));
    }  
  }, [respDc, editDc, accessToken, dispatch]); 

  useEffect (() => {
    initFetch();  
  }, [initFetch]);
```

I did try to put the complete function initFetch() inside the useEffect, i try to put the function with useCallback(), just right now.

I try to do this:

```
const initFetch = () => {
        for (let dc of respDc){
          dispatch(getTopicsByDcResponsable({dc: dc, token: accessToken}));      
        }
        for (let dc of editDc){
          dispatch(getTopicsbyDcentroEdit({dc: dc, token: accessToken}));
        }  
      };

 useEffect (() => {
        initFetch();  
      }, [respDc, editDc]);
```

The goal wiould be to achive that the initFetch, only would call if respDc or editDc, changed.

But i don't know which is the best solution.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

`JSON.parse()` will always create a new object, so `const initFetch = useCallback()` will also update on every single render. And since `initFetch` is new, `useEffect()` will also run it on every single render.

```
const { user } = useAuth();

const {
    responsable,
    editor,
    matricula
} = user;

useEffect(() => {
    const respDc = JSON.parse(responsable);
    const editDc = JSON.parse(editor);

    for (let dc of respDc) {
        dispatch(getTopicsByDcResponsable({ dc: dc, token: accessToken }));
    }

    for (let dc of editDc) {
        dispatch(getTopicsbyDcentroEdit({ dc: dc, token: accessToken }));
    }

}, [responsable, editor, accessToken, dispatch]);
```